# How do I get textview value from a listview?

Tags: android, listview, android-custom-view

I ve got a 15 items long list (with custom views with ) and I want to get the textview value of the list item that I want.

Comment: If they're just regular `TextView`s - i.e., not editable - wouldn't you already know the text values?

Comment: they are diferent dependable out of other variables in the custom view,they are averages of inputed numbers

Comment: and now I have a button out of the listview, and when i press it i want to get a text value depending on the position I pick

Answer (score 1):

Your onItemClick callback will like this

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    }
```

Here, you have `View view` you just cast this view using your layout and get your TextView . Here is example:

```
if (view != null) {
        TextView txtView = view.findViewById(R.id.mytextview);
        String value=txtView.getText().toString();
    }
```

**Edit:**

```
public View getViewByPosition(int pos, ListView listView) {
    final int firstListItemPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    final int lastListItemPosition = firstListItemPosition + listView.getChildCount() - 1;

    if (pos < firstListItemPosition || pos > lastListItemPosition ) {
        return listView.getAdapter().getView(pos, null, listView);
    } else {
        final int childIndex = pos - firstListItemPosition;
        return listView.getChildAt(childIndex);
    }
}
```

Just call this method on your button onClick() method using this way

```
getViewByPosition(2,YOUR_LIST_VIEW);
```

This method will return you `View` object of your `ListView` specific position. Now you can just cast it using previous way.

Hope , this will help you :)

Comment: Yes, but I dont need onITemClick I Have a button and that button will give me the text value in the list item at position 2 for example

Answer (score 0):

this code can be added to your ListView to make a certain action on long clicking  :

```
list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

               @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View list,int pos, long id) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                      CustomView view = (CustomView) list ;
                     //put in your customview some methods to get and set each item within it for example getTextViewText to get the text from the TextView item
                    }


                });
```